# If I user 2 web front ends as failover, what urls should the search crawler be using?

Tags: search, failover

IF I have 2 web front ends in a farm, both hosting websites and running central admin and all other services, on which farm should the search be running, if not on both, and what urls should it have in the content crawl, that of both web front ends? The point is, I Want the search to keep working even if one web front end shuts down..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want redundancy, you should enable Search Services on both WFE servers.
You probably have a Load Balancer for the traffic. You need crawl web applications urls and they must pointing to the NLB so if one server will go down, it will be redirected to another one.

You should have two applications servers too where one is for Central Administration and rest of services are running on both servers.

[Here is MS documentation about High Availability SP farms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/plan-for-high-availability)
[Second link for High Availability and Disaster Recovery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/high-availability-and-disaster-recovery-concepts)

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I have Central Admin running on both,. I do not an NLB for the time being, failover will be a manual process. So in that case, what should the URLs in the Search configuation be pointing at? Both Web Front ends?

Comment: URLs of WebApplications like https://intranet.company.com and the DNS record of this will point to NLB and NLB to WF1,WF2

Comment: you're welcom, dont forget mark asnwer as correct :)